# Cannot install newer version on android device

Tags: android, react-native

While testing my app one of the action I did is to clean install from PlayStore and then install update from my computer. When I did so I received the error INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE, there are a-lot of information in google about this error I understood that I need to increase the versionCode in build grade file, and I did so.
But then I started to receive the following error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package ###### signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!.
All suggestion that I can find is about uninstall the app from device and then clean install, and it does work. My question is why it happened? I am really concern about the customers who already have this app installed, they wan't be able to to update as well?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means, that the two APKs are signed with different signing keys.
If you try to install a debug version, the APK is signed with a debug key. So it is normal that the installation will fail.

In order to test the update of your app, either create a release version of your app (e.g. by selecting "release" from the "Build variants" tab. Or add the signing release configurations to your debug build variant in the app module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!

Comment: I added this section,
but when I am running the following command: ./gradlew assemblerelease -PkeyPw=$keyPw -PstorePw=$keyPw -PkeyAlias=androidkeystoresmbapp -PkeyLocation=$keyLocation  with real values I Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:signingConfigWriterRelease' property 'signingConfig.storeFile' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/olgal/Downloads/MyAppName.jks' as it does not exist. getting the following error:

Comment: The signingConfig section is look like: release {
            storeFile project.hasProperty('keyLocation') ? file(project.keyLocation) : file('default')
            storePassword project.hasProperty('storePw') ? project.storePw : 'default'
            keyAlias project.hasProperty('keyAlias') ? project.keyAlias : 'default'
            keyPassword project.hasProperty('keyPw') ? project.keyPw : 'default'
        }

Comment: It's looking for a keystore file and can't find it. Does the file `/Users/olgal/Downloads/MyAppName.jks` exist? If no, provide it.

Comment: After gave to it permission this error is gone. BUT I still not able to create the signed spk, in terminal it gave my this error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> /keyStorePath.jks (Operation not permitted)

And when I am trying to generate it via android studio I get the following: Cannot recover key.

Does something wrong with my credentials?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload your app to the Play Store you sign the app with a key. Now when you develop your app further and try to deploy it on your phone the app is either not signed or signed with a development key because it's only a development version of the app.

Therefore I assume you get this signature error because the app's signature just won't match. Once you upload a new version of your app to the Play Store you'll sign the app again with your key which results in the same signature and the Play Store will recognize your app as the same with a newer version.